# Websites do not respond on port 80, nginx die periodically

Tags: http, nginx, connection, port, plesk

I have a periodical problem in a server with Plesk, the `Port 80` is not listened but `7080` is listened so the websites do not respond on the `Port 80`.

```
#netstat -tlpn | grep :80

#netstat -tlpn | grep :7080
tcp 0 0 :::7080 :::* LISTEN 3009/httpd
# plesk sbin nginxmng -s
Enabled
```

I resolve this problem executing the following commands but after few minutes the problem returns periodically:

```
pkill -9 nginx
# service nginx start
Starting nginx: [ OK ]

# /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/nginxmng -d
# /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/nginxmng -e
# service nginx restart
Starting nginx: [ OK ]
```

Source: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213926725-Websites-do-not-respond-on-80-port-but-respond-properly-on-7080-port

How can i finally fix this error? I am thinking to add a `crontab` running the commands that i have used to solve the error but i think that it is not a good idea.

Comment: Have you checked why nginx dies? `/var/log/nginx/error.log` may contain this info.

Comment: @ Elvis Plesky
There are the following errors:
`
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
*18 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
*26 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
*29 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
*26 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not describe why nginx keep getting stopped. Try `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/plesk/rc_actions.log` also.

Comment: @Elvis Plesky you can find the content of both the files on:

[/var/log/messages](https://codepen.io/daniele0410/pen/pQpwEZ)

AND

[/var/log/plesk/rc_actions.log](https://codepen.io/daniele0410/pen/zMpzdg)